# How to include header, footer, sidebar to webpage in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I newly joined asp.net, I am little bit confused how to add header/footer to webpage?

I am using visual studio 2012.

We use include,require predefined functions in PHP.

I dont know what we use in asp.net for none changeable blocks for website.

Please advise me.

Thanks

Comment: Use `Master page` for WebForms and `Layout` for MVC

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: If you're new to asp.net I suggest that you go to http://asp.net and follow a few starter tutorials.

Comment: Are you using WebForms or MVC?

Comment: @Hanno Totally agree with this. Even if this question is answered, no doubt OP will get stuck at every hurdle until they've read a tutorial

Comment: yes, I am using WebForms

Comment: Webforms are OK. Dont be confused by reading comments against webforms. Look into masterpages.

Comment: @abhitalks Just preference - it's a lot easier to Unit Test MVC, the coding naturally lays itself out more logically also Razor syntax is a lot slicker than the WebForms syntax.

Comment: Please, don't be selfish and be grateful with the time people waste here to help you and at least accept a valid answer. People will not help you anymore if they see that you are that selfish.

Answer (score 1):

Using Masterpages, allows you to create master copies of your header, footer, sidebar and what else. All your "content" pages inherit the masterpage, and renders in a predefined "content area" inside the masterpage.

Create a masterpage, it should have a default "content placeholder". Build your masterpage around it, and when adding a new page, choose "content page", or in earlier Visual Studio editions, page, and check the box that says "use masterpage".

You will then see your new content page with the masterpage faded out on the background, and you can build your content page.

Calling the content page (normal page that is bound to a masterpage), always renders the masterpage and the content page as one page to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

use master page and add header div and footer as you need.

```
<div style="margin-left: 38%; width: 25%;">
    Header
 </div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <div style="margin-left: 38%; width: 25%;">
        <hr style="color: #1B3280; border-width: thin; width: 98%;" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label" runat="server" CssClass="rights" Font-Size="12px" Font-Names="Calibri"
            Text="All rights reserved."></asp:Label>
    </div>
```